# IMemoryCache remove key when db table is changed

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a service class **PersonsCachingService** for caching and i need to reset "allpersons" key when number of records in this table is changed.
In PHP frameworks like Yii2 or Symfony such task is easy but i don't understand better way to do this in Asp Core.
Could you propose any?

```
public class   PersonsCachingService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private static readonly int timeInSeconds = 30;

    public PersonsCachingService(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all table from cache
    /// </summary>
    public IList<Person> AllPersons
    {
        get
        {
            string cacheKey = "allpersons";
            if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out IList<Person> persons)) return persons;
            else
            {
                persons = _dbContext.Persons.ToList();
                _memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, persons, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                    .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeInSeconds)));
                return persons;
            }

        }
    }}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Cache Dependency in ASP.NET Core](http://hishambinateya.com/cache-dependency-in-asp.net-core) which should get you started.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reset'?

Comment: remove key in memoryCache